# Android device does not load project theme

Tags: android, xml, android-styles

I created a new project and am trying to create a new theme in my `values/styles.xml` I have created the values-v11, values-v14, values-v19...etc, and added styles.xml files to all.  The theme matches in my manifest file and the preview screen loads the correct theme.  However when I run it on my device (galaxy s4) the theme does not load.

here is my styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

    </style>


</resources>
```

I have cleaned the project, deleted the app from my device. Any advice to fix?

Comment: Which version of android is ur galaxy s4 and which version u have seen the preview screen?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not applying the theme at application/activity level.

If you are applying theme at application/activity level,still problem occurs.Please post the manifest file for more assistance.

Make sure you check the build version code of your S4 device and check the mapping values folder(Ex: values-v11,values-v14  etc).

Build version codes link(for your reference):
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html